# Removing the "Try Ubuntu/Install It" dialog from a custom ISO on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I try to remove the Welcome Screen (and automatically choose "Try Ubuntu" option) on a live USB stick.

One Option on 16.04 was to change `syslinux/syslinux.cfg`. I can not find this on my Ubuntu 18.04 live stick. Am I blind or was it changed?

Comment: Found the solution, instead of `syslinux.cfg` one needs to change `isolinux.cfg`

Comment: Please write your own answer and accept it as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Answer (score 2):

[The following comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145754/removing-the-try-ubunut-install-it-dialog-from-a-custom-iso-on-ubuntu-18-02/1276345#comment1902742_1145754) was posted as an answer by the original author of this question:

> Found the solution, instead of `syslinux.cfg` one needs to change `isolinux.cfg`

Comment: Change what in that file?